# Reads a word and prints all substrings, sorted by length in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, substring

I have code a program to reads a word and prints all substrings, sorted by length. For example, if the user provides the input  "rum" , the program prints
 
r 
     u 
     m 
     ru 
     um 
     rum

Code below is what I have done and manage to print:
 
r 
     u 
     m 
     ru 
     um 
     m

The problem that I'm not understand, how to make the loop print the correct output for the last word from 'm' to 'rum' .. what did I miss?

If anyone able to point the way to correct my loop in my code, I would really appreciated. Many thanks!

```
word = input("\nPlease enter a word : ")
length = 1
pos = 0

for i in range(length, len(word)):
    for j in range(pos, len(word)):
        print(word[j:i+j])
```

Comment: What do you observe if you also print the `i` and `j` values?

Comment: You could try to print both i and j to see the slice positions. Try to write down the correct slices on paper to figure out the pattern and problem

Comment: i'm still tracing it, but i can't find what I'm missing in my loop statement to print the last string index position at j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just put print() to see what is j and i+j every time your for loop processed. Here is the problem;

```
word = input("\nPlease enter a word : ")
length = 1
pos = 0

for i in range(length, len(word)):
    for j in range(pos, len(word)):
        print (j)
        print (i+j)
        print(word[j:i+j])
        print ("------------")
```

Output:

```
>>> 

Please enter a word : rum
0
1 #word[0:1]
r
------------
1
2 #word[1:2]
u
------------
2
3 #word[2:3]
m
------------
0
2  #word[0:2]
ru
------------
1
3  #word[1:3]
um
------------
2
4 #word[2:4] which is only m.
m
------------
>>>
```

Your codes trying to print `word[2:4]` at the last part which is only `m`.That's the problem, that's why it only prints `m` instead of whole word.

Use `combinations()` it's better.

```
from itertools import combinations

word = "rum"
for x in range(len(word)+1):
    for c in combinations(word,x):
        print ("".join(c))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
r
u
m
ru
rm
um
rum
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. This is what i'm looking for. Should use combination in my nested for loop.  Many thanks, sir!

Comment: @niese np, if it solved your question please check it as correct answer for the future visiters.

Comment: Use `combination`, can't make sure the substring is consecutive. Imagine that `abcde` - `ace`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def grouper(l, n):
    """get a generator of n consecutive items from a given list 
    """
    # the last element is l[-n:]
    for i in range(len(l)-n+1): 
        yield l[i:i+n]

word = 'abcde'
result = [s for i in range(1, len(word)+1) for s in grouper(word, n=i)]

print(result)
# Output
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'abcde']
```

This might be helpful to understand Python's slice notation.

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | a | b | c | d | e |
 +---+---+---+---+---+
   0   1   2   3   4  
  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

- the list returned by [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) does NOT include `stop`, so your first `range` use (in the outer loop) should be `range(length, len(word)+1)`
- the second range use has an unexpected larger `stop`, which should depend on the `i` of the outer loop, which I think is the current length

here is corrected code:

```
word = 'rum'
for length in range(1, len(word)+1):
    for pos in range(0, len(word)-length+1):
        print(word[pos:pos+length])
```

Comment: Thanks.. but nope it does not work that way. Run nicely in java but not in python.

Comment: Yeah if you're using python 3, then parentheses around the print statement are needed.

Comment: niese, as @RoadRunner pointed out, if you're using python3, you need to  add parentheses to the print. (I've updated the code, which runs in Python 2)

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. Yup, it did run in python 3. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go man, using a while loop will solve your problem.

```
    word = input("\nPlease enter a word : ")
    j=1
    result = []
    while True:
        for i in range(len(word)-j+1):
            result.append(word[i:i+j])
        if j==len(word):
            break
        j+=1

    for substr in result:
        print(substr)

    # Output
    r
    u
    m
    ru
    um
    rum
```

This code off course can be more concise, but it does do the job. It's also a very common method for getting distinct substrings out of string.